# Ascending and Descending Sort in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-pipe

Why is it that sort function is working :

```
<th (click)="sort('transaction_date')">Transaction Date <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'transaction_date', 'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'transaction_date' && isDesc), 'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'transaction_date' && !isDesc) }" aria-hidden="true"> </i></th>
```

WHILE THIS ONE ISN'T WORKING :

```
<th (click)="sort('user.name')">User <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'user.name', 'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'user.name' && isDesc), 'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'user.name' && !isDesc) }" aria-hidden="true"> </i></th>
```

> html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let inner of order.purchase_orders | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}">
        <td>{{ inner.transaction_date | date  }}</td>
        <td>{{ inner.user.name  }}</td>
 </tr>
```

> ts

```
sort(property){
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc; //change the direction    
    this.column = property;
    this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
    console.log(property);
  };
```

> pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})

export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
    if(records && records.length >0 ){
    return records.sort(function(a, b){
          if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
            return -1 * args.direction;
          }
          else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
            return 1 * args.direction;
          }
          else{
            return 0;
          }
        });
      }
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue here is :
>
> Nested property of object, orderBy must be providing the sorting on
>   the basis of first level of properties

I am considering, `inner` should be look like this,

```
{
    transaction_date : '10/12/2014'
    user : {
        name : 'something',
        ...
    }
}
```

try to make this object like, take all sortable property on first level 
( OR you must have to change the orderBy that way )

```
{
    transaction_date : '10/12/2014'
    user_name : 'something',
    user : {
        name : 'something',
        ...
    }
}
```

And try.

```
<th (click)="sort('user_name')">
    User <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'user_name', 
                                    'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'user_name' && isDesc), 
                                    'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'user_name' && !isDesc) }" 
            aria-hidden="true"> 
        </i>
</th>
```

---

Add `records.map(record => record['user_name'] = record.user.name);` , to your `transform` function , like this :

This will make the object as I suggested :

```
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
    if(records && records.length >0 ){

    records.map(record => record['user_name'] = record.user.name); // add here

    return records.sort(function(a, b){
        ....
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: I've added the pipe above. Yes you are right. Inner is this {
    transaction_date : '10/12/2014'
    user : {
        name : 'something',
        ...
    }
}

Comment: But I want the user : { name : 'something', ... } } to be read. I already have the transaction_date be read but the user.name can't be read

Comment: How can i do that since i have to put transaction_date and user.name at the same time?

Comment: It works. Do i have to add  records.map(record => record['user_name'] = record.user.name); Because i have many situations in my app like this?