# Angular pipe sorting

Tags: angular, sorting, pipe

According to this question -> [Ascending and Descending Sort in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47049077/5827523)

I've made the same pipe, but it can't sort numbers naturally. I mean 2 is > then 11.

How can this pipe be modified to sort both string and numbers?

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'orderBy'
})

export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
        if (records && records.length > 0) {
            return records.sort(function (a, b) {                 
                if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
                    return -1 * args.direction;
                } else if (a[args.property] > b[args.property]) {
                    return 1 * args.direction;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give examples, what your input and args looks like and what output you expect?

Comment: Hi, actually its exactly same as from link. Inputs are values from html table column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are sorting the values as strings - lexicographically. The input for your pipe seems to be of type `Array<{ [propertyName: string]: [value: string] }>`.

Either make sure that the input property values are numbers or convert the values to `number` before comparing.

In case you need to sort based on the type of the data that came to your pipe, you can use something like this:

```ts
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
    if (records && records.length > 0) {
      return records.sort(
        (a, b) => args.direction * (
          typeof a[args.property] === 'number'
            ? (a[args.property] - b[args.property])
            : a[args.property] > b[args.property] ? 1 : -1)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps a little :-)

Answer (score 1):

### This is my solution for ordering in Angular with pipe.

+Extra feature: Ascending and Descending with the third parameter.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], key: string, dir: number = 1): any {
    if (!value || !key) {
      return value;
    }

    value.sort( (a, b) => {
      return ('' + a[key]).localeCompare( ('' + b[key]) ) * dir;
    });

    return value;
  }

}
```

I always cast values to a string, because the comparing is easiest.